# Is there a way to adjust the brightness and intensity of colors to introduce a readable signal(data) into the image and retrieve it

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, image-recognition, steganography

I'm doing a sample project on a topic related to Image Recognition where I would like to embed data inside an image, then take a snapshot of the image and retrieve the embeded data from the snapshot image.

Problem Statement: I'm able to embed the data in the image but I'm unable to retrieve the same data from the snapshot image.
**Is there a way to adjust the brightness and intensity of colours to introduce a readable signal(data) into the image and retrieve it from a snapshot image?**

Example: I would like to achieve what Digimarc Watermarking is currently doing here https://www.digimarc.com/resources/video/how-it-works

It would be great if you guys could provide me any links to do further reseach on solving this issue.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Just a heads up, people don't respond to questions based on how urgent they are, but on how useful or well constructed they are. You'd be advised to read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on asking.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I'm unable to crack my problem and I'm looking for some experts help who could guide me by providing their inputs in-order to solve this problem.

Comment: How much image processing background do you have? This sounds like not a suitable project for a beginner to me. A lot will depend on the quality of the "snapshot", too.